# Comma needed when applying these 3 adjectives to a noun being introduced?

Tags: commas, orthography

Copyediting this sentence:

> Create a new, integrated and dynamic platform

I'm unsure if the comma after "new" is needed or not, or if one should go between "integrated and dynamic".

Is the quoted statement correct grammatically, or if not how should it be changed to correct its grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence as you have it is grammatically correct. (If you simply removed the comma, it would not be.)

But it's a matter of style if you want to punctuate it differently.

You could add another comma if you want to use a serial comma. (Which is typically more common in North America than in the UK. But that's hardly a rule, and more of a general guideline. Many people in North America dislike the serial comma, and many in the UK do like it. It's still up to you, any company you might work for, and your particular audience.)

Or, if there was an older platform that was also integrated and dynamic, you could say:

> Create a new integrated-and-dynamic platform.

Or, perhaps (if it was broken, the integration was lost, and you want to repair it):

> Create a newly integrated and dynamic platform.